# Multiple tikzpictures in a standalone document

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I have a `standalone` document of the form:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[remember picture, baseline] \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=base] (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node (A) {
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & \tikzmark{two}{2} \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}};

\node[right=of A] (B) {
\begin{tabular}{ll}
5 & 6 \\
\tikzmark{seven}{7} & 8 \\
\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[->] (two) -- (seven);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The contents are displayed correctly when using the `article` `documentclass` instead of `standalone`.

Can anyone suggest how to make it so that the contents of all `tikzpicture`s are displayed?

Comment: The way you are doing it causes `pdflatex` to put every `tikzpicture` on a separate page of the document. Do you want all your `tikzpictures` on one page?

Comment: All of the `tikzpicture`s fit on a single page. Some of the contents of the second and third ones are overlaid on the first. I have tried `\documentclass[tikz=true]{standalone}`, but this isn't displaying the contents correctly, either.

Comment: Don't use different `tikzpicture`s. Put all drawing inside a single `tikzpicture` environment. `standalone` produces one page per `tikzpicture` environment you are using (by design).

Comment: I presume from you comment that you use `\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{tikz}` and not `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` as this separates the `tikzpictures` on single pages. As @HarishKumar says, don't use different `tikzpicture`s, try to use `scopes` in one `tikzpicture` instead.

Comment: The reason I need multiple `tikzicture`s is that inside the first `tikzpicture`, there are tabular environments, some of the elements of which are inline `\tikz`s. These elements cannot be referred to in the containing `tikzpicture`. They are referred to in the following `tikzpicture`s. On the preamble: The last thing I tried was `\documentclass[multi=tikzpicture, ignorerest=true]{standalone} \usepackage{tikz}`, again to no avail.

Comment: From your last comment seems that you are using `tikzpictures` inside `tikzpictures` which is better not to do. Could you show us some code where we can see what's your intention and wha'ts the problem with `standalone`?

Comment: I have edited my post with a link to the full code. What I am doing is surrounding some of the entries in the tables with named `node`s so that the positions of these nodes can later be used in drawing arrows. These nodes within `tabular` environment may only be referred to in subsequent `tikzpicture` environments.

Comment: Please post a Minimal Working Example *here* so that your question remains useful to others. A link to code elsewhere is likely to stop working and then your question will be of no use.

Comment: I have now edited the post to include only a MWE which illustrates my problem.

Comment: Eh, yes, the `\tikzmark`s can be referred to in the containing `tikzpicture`, did you try that?

Comment: I was not aware that this was possible. I just tried using a single `tikzpicture`, and with the `documentclass` `article`, it works. When I compile it with `standalone`, it alternates between a) giving me an error `! Dimension too large`, referring to the `draw` command and b) "successfully" compiling to a document that does not display the contents correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine with just one `tikzpicture` here. You have to compile twice of course.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[remember picture, baseline] \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=base] (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node (A) {
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & \tikzmark{two}{2} \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}};

\node[right=of A] (B) {
\begin{tabular}{ll}
5 & 6 \\
\tikzmark{seven}{7} & 8 \\
\end{tabular}};

\draw[->] (two) -- (seven);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works on my end as well. It turns out that the "overlay" option that I'd given to the single `tikzpicture` environment was what was creating the problem. I applied this to my original code, and that works fine as well.