# how to put images beside

Tags: graphics

how can I put these two images beside each other, How can I do that?

code I tried

I am attaching figure it look like this.[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

%\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}[!tbp]
%    \begin{subfigure}[b]
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{97}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=2.0, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex,tdplot_main_coords]

\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0)node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0)node[below]{$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3.5)node[left]{$z$};
\draw[fill] (0,0,0) circle (0.5pt) node[above, left]{$o$};


\draw[thick] (2.5,1,0) -- (2.5,1.5,0) -- (1.5,1.7,0) -- (1.5,1.2,0) -- (2.5,1,0) -- (0,0.7,2)node[below]{$ $}; %cube lower square

\draw[thick] (0,1.2,1.7) -- (0,0.7,2) -- (0,1,2.8) -- (0,1.5,2.5) -- (0,1.2,1.7) node[below]{$ $}; %cube upper square

\draw[thick] (0,1.2,1.7) -- (2.5,1.5,0) node[below]{$ $};
\draw[thick] (0,1.5,2.5) -- (1.5,1.7,0) node[below]{$ $};
\draw[thick, dashed] (0,1,2.8) -- (1.5,1.2,0) node[below]{$ $};


\draw[fill] (0,1.18,2.3) circle (0.5pt) node[above, left]{$ $};
\draw[thick,->] (0,1.18,2.3) -- (0,1.18,3.6)node[below, left]{$\hat{k}$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,1.18,2.3) -- (0,2,3.6)node[below, right]{$\widehat{n_k}$};

\draw[thick] (0,1.18,3.2) .. controls (0,1.18,3.3) and (0,1.6,3.4) .. (0,1.74,3.2); %angle
\draw[fill] (0,1.5,3.31) circle (0.05pt) node[above]{$ \gamma_k $};

%\draw (0,0) node[minimum size=2cm,draw] {square};
%\draw (0,-2) node[minimum size=2cm,draw,circle] {circle};



\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{subfigure}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\hfill
% \begin{subfigure}[b]
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{97}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=2.0, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex,tdplot_main_coords]

\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0)node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0)node[below]{$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3.5)node[left]{$z$};
\draw[fill] (0,0,0) circle (0.5pt) node[above, left]{$o$};


\draw[thick] (2.5,1,0) -- (2.5,1.5,0) -- (1.5,1.7,0) -- (1.5,1.2,0) -- (2.5,1,0) -- (0,0.7,2)node[below]{$ $}; %cube lower square

\draw[thick, rotate=90] (0,1.9,-1.2) ellipse (18pt and 30pt);% upper circle
\draw[thick, rotate=90] (0,-1.1,-1.27) ellipse (18pt and 30pt);% lower circle

%\draw[thick] (0,1.2,1.7) -- (0,0.7,2) -- (0,1,2.8) -- (0,1.5,2.5) -- (0,1.2,1.7) node[below]{$ $}; %cube upper square
\draw[thick] (0,0.7,2) .. controls (0,1,2) and (0,1,2) .. (0,1.2,1.7);
\draw[thick] (0,0.7,2) .. controls (0,0.7,1.8) and (0,0.7,2.4) .. (0,1,2.8);
\draw[thick] (0,1,2.8) .. controls (0,1.1,2.8) and (0,1.2,2.8) .. (0,1.5,2.5);
\draw[thick] (0,1.5,2.5) .. controls (0,1.4,2.3) and (0,1.3,2.4) .. (0,1.2,1.7);




\draw[thick] (0,1.2,1.7) -- (2.5,1.5,0) node[below]{$ $};
\draw[thick] (0,1.5,2.5) -- (1.5,1.7,0) node[below]{$ $};
\draw[thick, dashed] (0,1,2.8) -- (1.5,1.2,0) node[below]{$ $};


\draw[fill] (0,1.18,2.3) circle (0.5pt) node[above, left]{$ $};
\draw[thick,->] (0,1.18,2.3) -- (0,1.18,3.6)node[below, left]{$\hat{k}$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,1.18,2.3) -- (0,2,3.6)node[below, right]{$\widehat{n_k}$};

\draw[thick] (0,1.18,3.2) .. controls (0,1.18,3.3) and (0,1.6,3.4) .. (0,1.74,3.2); %angle


% Points
\draw[fill] (0,1.5,2.5) circle (0.05pt) node[above, right]{$ \Delta{S_k} $};

\draw[fill] (2.5,1.24,0) circle (0.05pt) node[below]{$ \Delta{y_k} $};
\draw[fill] (2,1.6,0) circle (0.05pt) node[below, right]{$ \Delta{x_k} $};
\draw[fill] (1.7,1.16,0) circle (0.05pt) node[below]{$ \Delta{A_k} $};
\draw[fill] (2.96,0.6,0) circle (0.05pt) node[below]{$ R $};
\draw[fill] (0,0.4,1.7) circle (0.05pt) node[below]{$ S $};
\draw[fill] (0,1,2.6) circle (0.05pt) node[below, left]{$ (x_k,y_k,z_k) $};





%\draw (0,0) node[minimum size=2cm,draw] {square};
%\draw (0,-2) node[minimum size=2cm,draw,circle] {circle};



\end{tikzpicture}


%\end{subfigure}
%  \caption{fig 11}

%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Multiple tikzpictures in a standalone document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197436/134144)

Comment: (A) don't put blank lines between the pictures (\hfill is always good).  (B) make sure both pictures will fit on one line.  (C) Don't use the [tikz] option for standalone (or [multi=tikzpicture]).

Comment: thanks Sir for your kind suggestions. can you give me an example